# Why are the below file paths correct....ejs ,nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I have been trying to learn how to make a simple chat App using `nodejs`
along with `express`, `ejs`, `socket.io`

Below is a working repo I cloned from 
 https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp

Folder Structure for `simplechatApp`

> app.js
>
> views
>
> public

views

> index.js

public

> chat.js
>
> style.js

This is the `app.js` file in which I rendered the `index.js` file and used public ..

[image: the app.js in the simpleChatApp folder]

Now the Problem is in the second pic ...in the index.ejs file
Here when I am linking it with the external css file (style.css) which is in another folder (namely the public folder).....How can I be writing href=style.css  I think this shouldn't work  for files in different folder ..... but it seems to work

[image: the index.js in views folder in simpleChatApp folder]

Similarly here when including the external chat.js which is a different folder again writing src ="chat.js" works , but again I think it shouldn;t be working for a file in a different folder

[image: the index.js in views folder in simpleChatApp folder]

Can Someone please explain how is this working ....this is my first project so I am not much used to all this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at middleware:

[Middleware](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-node-js-middleware-works-d8e02a936113)

[middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

You can find this below statement in app.js file

app.use(express.static('public'))

the above line means :

Serving static files in Express. To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express. The function signature is: express. static(root, [options]) The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets.

By using middleware we can access style.css and chat.js file in index.ejs file

Comment: Ok my app.js file knows this ....that hey go to the public folder if not specified.....but my index.ejs file doesn't know that .....so using it in the index.ejs file whilst the middleware is used in qpp.js doesn't seem quite fine ...

Comment: also isnt't a / required even then